# withSum in deep nested relationship in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I could not find this in the laravel docs on aggregate relationships

I was able to do something like this

```php
    private function refreshUsers()
    {
        $this->users = User::withSum(['taskTimeSessions'=> function ($query) {
                                    $query->whereMonth('created_at',$this->month)
                                            ->where('is_reconciled',1);
                        }],'session_duration_in_seconds')
                        ->get();
    }
```

But now I am trying to query what is the total time a `Sprint` has or at the very least what the individual tasks inside a sprint have so that I can just sum the total of those somehow.

- Sprint has many SprintTasks (pivot table)
- SprintTask belongs to one Task
- Task has many TaskTimeSessions

So I am trying to go find the total time of the TaskTimeSessions

```php
Sprint::with([
'sprintTasks.task'=> function ($query) {
    $query->withSum('taskTimeSessions','session_duration_in_seconds');
   }])
->get();
```

I am not getting any errors, but not finding the result anywhere when `dd`

I thought i would get lucky and have something like this work

```php
->withSum('sprintTasks.task.taskTimeSessions', 'session_duration_in_seconds')
```

But I am getting this error

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\Sprint::sprintTasks.task()
```

If anyone can help me out with some guidance on how to go about this, even if it doesn't include withSum it would be much appreciated.

As requested, these are the models.

```
// Sprint
public function sprintTasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SprintTask::class, 'sprint_id');
    }
    


// SprintTask
protected $fillable = [
        'sprint_id',
        'task_id',
        'is_completed'
    ];

public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class,'task_id');
    }

public function sprint()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class,'sprint_id');
    }



// Task
public function taskTimeSessions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TaskTimeSession::class, 'task_id');
    }



// TaskTimeSessions
protected $fillable = [
        'task_id',
        'session_duration_in_seconds'
    ];
    

public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class,'task_id');
    }
```

Is it possible to abstract this into the model as like

```
public function totalTaskTime() {
 // using the relationship stuff to figure out the math and return it? 

}
```

Looking for any advice on what the best approach is to do this.

Right now I am literally doing this in the blade and seems very bad

```php
@php
    $timeTracked = 0;
    
    foreach ($sprint->sprintTasks as $sprintTask) {
        $timeTracked += $sprintTask->task->time_tracked_in_seconds;
    }
@endphp
```

Comment: How about `hasManyThrough` ? -> https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Also can you add your models ?

Comment: @xenooooo I added the models if that helps clarify the situation

Comment: I tried the hasManyThrough, but since I did not call the column the larave default tries to find `sprint_task_id` I am not sure how to  change `return $this->hasManyThrough( Task::class, SprintTask::class );` so it finds `sprint_Id`

Comment: I did try `hasManyThrough( Task::class, SprintTask::class, 'task_id', 'sprint_id', ` but doesn't seem to fix it, and I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a many to many relation between sprint and task

For that you can setup a direct relation `belongsToMany` with sprint_tasks as the pivot table

```
// Sprint
public function sprintTasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SprintTask::class, 'sprint_id');
}

public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'sprint_tasks', 'sprint_id', 'task_id')->withPivot('is_completed');
}
```

Now you can use that relation to query your needs

```
Sprint::with(['tasks'=> function ($query) {
    $query->withSum('taskTimeSessions','session_duration_in_seconds');
}])
->get();
```

Comment: Yea, I am planning on rebuilding this project app. So not all of my decisions where sound haha. I was thinking that could make weekly sprints, and if a task didn't get finished could just assign it to another sprint. So it has some sort of history of attempts. I have been working on this app for 2 years since I started learning coding and remade it 6 times so far lol, this time around trying to learn all the best practices for the trouble situations

Comment: @Jakub actually you are right, a task can belong to multiple sprints. good luck with your app, if you need help with laravel, dont hesitate to look me up (linkedin)

Comment: Will do that, and thanks again for the help :D

Answer (score 3):

There is a good package for Laravel for complex relationships - [eloquent-has-many-deep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep). You can use it to build relationships through an unlimited number of tables.

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep:"^1.7"
```

Sprint.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasManyDeep;
use Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

class Sprint extends Model
{
    use HasRelationships;

    public function tasks(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'sprint_tasks');
    }

    public function taskTimeSessions(): HasManyDeep
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeepFromRelations($this->tasks(), (new Task())->taskTimeSessions());
    }
}
```

Task.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Task extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function taskTimeSessions(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TaskTimeSession::class);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
$sprints = Sprint::withSum('taskTimeSessions', 'session_duration_in_seconds')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I would prefer to not use 3rd party packages whenever possible as it will just complicate things more in the long run with maintaining a project.